# How to connect with MSAccess database in Java using Jboss 5.0.0 GA

Tags: java, eclipse, ms-access, jboss, datasource

I have problem with connecting Dynamic Web Project and database MS Access. I'm using Eclipse Juno, and Jboss 5.0.0 GA. I know that i have to define datasource xml. But I don't know what I'm doing wrong.I stored msaccess-ds.xml in jboss-5.0.0.GA\server\default\deploy folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!--  JBoss Server Configuration                                           -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!-- ===================================================================== -->

<!-- $Id: msaccess-ds.xml 8941 2002-07-22 22:57:24Z d_jencks $ -->
<!-- ==================================================================== -->
<!-- This uses the sun jdbc-odbc driver, so don't expect miracles          -->
<!-- Thanks to Alan Moor, who warns...                                     -->
<!-- Remember, though, never trust critical data, or data that you can't   -->
<!-- afford to lose, or data that you need quick access to, or data that   -->
<!-- needs to be secure, to Microsoft Access.                              -->
<!-- ===================================================================== -->


<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>MSAccessDS</jndi-name>
    <!-- format of URL is "jdbc:odbc:DSNNAME" -->
    <connection-url>jdbc:odbc:C:\Users\Tazz\Desktop\bazaAccess\baza niekod\tabele Faelbud caĹ‚oĹ›Ä‡_wb.mdb</connection-url>
    <driver-class>sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver</driver-class>
    <user-name></user-name>
    <password></password>
  </local-tx-datasource>

</datasources>
```

And here is my Java Code:

```
public static void connectMSAccess(){

        try {
            InitialContext cxt = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) cxt.lookup( "java:comp/env/MSAccessDS" );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

And this is my problem:

```
11:49:34,187 ERROR [STDERR] javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: MSAccessDS not bound
11:49:34,187 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:771)
11:49:34,187 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:779)
11:49:34,187 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:785)
11:49:34,187 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:443)
11:49:34,187 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:399)
11:49:34,187 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:713)
11:49:34,187 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
11:49:34,187 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:673)
11:49:34,187 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
11:49:34,187 ERROR [STDERR]     at pl.test.connection.MSAccessConnector.connectMSAccess(MSAccessConnector.java:12)
11:49:34,187 ERROR [STDERR]     at pl.test.connection.Serwlet.doGet(Serwlet.java:29)
11:49:34,187 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
11:49:34,187 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
11:49:34,187 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
11:49:34,197 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
11:49:34,197 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
11:49:34,197 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
11:49:34,197 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
11:49:34,197 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
11:49:34,197 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
11:49:34,197 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
11:49:34,197 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
11:49:34,197 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
11:49:34,197 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
11:49:34,197 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
11:49:34,197 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
11:49:34,197 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
11:49:34,197 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
11:49:34,197 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
11:49:34,197 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:828)
11:49:34,197 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)
11:49:34,197 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
11:49:34,197 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I created simply console application to connecting with this database and everything was ok, but there i didn't have to use datasource and jboss. Please help me!

Comment: You have some pretty wild Unicode characters in your connection-URL; it even contains the `>` char which makes it invalid XML. Have you double-checked this?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I changed this name of file to ala.mdb but unfortunately i have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

should be `context.lookup("java:/MSAccessDS");`

Comment: I tried this earlier and I had this problem: ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource cannot be cast to javax.activation.DataSource

Comment: Remove any jar files that include db libraries other than the jboss ones. Can you paste all of your included jars?

Comment: I forgot write that I don't have any jar files in jboss-5.0.0.GA\server\default\lib folder because I don't know what it should be. In console app I used Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver") it was the most often  solution, that i found. I can't find this sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver. Could tell me what I should store to jboss-5.0.0.GA\server\default\lib folder?